# How can I get object by specific parameter in GrahpQl with HotChocolate C#

Tags: c#, .net, graphql, hotchocolate

I am using HotChocolate library to work with GraphQL via .NET. I already can get all objects, that are stored in db, using this query:

```
query 
{
    news
    {
        title
        description
    }
}
```

But I need to have an opportunity, to select object with specific id like in this query:

```
query
{
    news(id: 5) 
    {
        title
        description
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following exception

> Unknown argument "id" on field "Query.news".

I use this code to get all news from database and return it to a client:

```
    [UseDbContext(typeof(Context.Context))]
    [UseFiltering]
    [UseSorting]
    public IQueryable<Entities.News> GetNews([ScopedService] Context.Context context)
    {
        return context.News;
    }
```

Also I tried to get an object by id using this code:

```
    [UseDbContext(typeof(Context.Context))]
    [UseFiltering]
    [UseSorting]
    public Entities.News GetNews(int id, [ScopedService] Context.Context context)
    {
        return context.News.Find(id);
    }
```

But I іtill have the exception when trying to get it by id

Comment: I assume your `News` class has a field called ID?

Comment: @ChrisHammond Yes, I have such field

Comment: Is you question about specifying the ID in Graph Query, or when getting data from DB?

Comment: @ChrisHammond I mean, I want to have an opportunity to send query, where I can write news(id:4){name}, and I will have name for news with id 4, and now if I will write such query, I will have an exeption in graphQl. Query dont understand what "id" is

Comment: Please add the class definition of `Context.Context.News` to your question

Comment: It sounds like your schema definition is not exposing as expected

Answer (score 0):

With the `UseFiltering` attribute, this exposes a new schema "descriptor" of `WHERE` and you can then use this in your Graph QL query

```
query ($searchId: Int!)
{
    news(where: {id: {eq:  $searchId}}) 
    {
        title
        description
    }
}
variables {
    "searchId" : 1
}
```

Comment: I know about this feature, but I need to take this as a parameter

Comment: @andruhevich - You can define `variables` in the query body - I have updated my answer

Comment: Sorry, but it still not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: *no, you cannot proceed that way.*

The explanation: the attribute [UseFiltering] can be applied to something that presents a collection of items only. In the second method with 'id', you are trying to return the single entity along with [UseFiltering]. It's not possible.

So, in total, you have the following options (which all do not conform to your needs exactly):

1. You follow the way in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72448869/876743) - as for me, it is the most logically correct approach.
2. You can add the parameter 'id' to the method GetNews but still return IQueryable containing the single element or nothing - as for me, the most non-intuitive approach because the selection by single id is logically incompatible with filtering by WHERE, results ordering and pagination.
3. Create a separate method GetUserById returning a single element - as for me, the correct approach which is often used along with p.1.